# How to setup Vim LSP plugins to use clangd on a Visual C++ project (msbuild, cl.exe)?

Tags: filetype-c++, lsp

How do you setup clangd as an lsp when using a project not built with clang?

It's giving really basic lint errors like `unknown type name 'uint8_t'` because it's failing to process my precompiled headers. And completion mostly doesn't work.

Comment: Using different toolchains for linting and compiling doesn't sound like a particularly good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

clangd [wants a compile_commands.json file](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/JSONCompilationDatabase.html). I found the [Sourcetrail Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vs-publisher-1208751.SourcetrailExtension) for Visual Studio will generate compile_commands.json:

> As a Clang based tool Sourcetrail supports the JSON Compilation
> Database format for simplified project setup. This extension enables
> you to generate a JSON Compilation Database from your Visual Studio
> projects and solutions.

Install that extension, restart visual studio, and then Sourcetrail > Create Compilation Database, then Select All, and click Create.

That cleared up a lot of my linting errors, and I sometimes get good completion results with `omnifunc=lsp#complete`. Sometimes I get nothing.

I think compile_commands.json needs to be regularly regenerated since it lists compilation commands for each file. I wish there was an easy way to automate this step.

---

I'm using several plugins for lsp and linting support:

- [vim-lsp](https://github.com/prabirshrestha/vim-lsp)
- [vim-lsp-settings](https://github.com/mattn/vim-lsp-settings)
- [vim-lsp-ale](https://github.com/rhysd/vim-lsp-ale)
- [ale](https://github.com/dense-analysis/ale)